# Angular : pass mutliple values to the controller

Tags: angularjs, input

Let's say i have a drop drown list that i add dynamicly in my html template:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addRow()" style="margin-bottom:5px;">Add cities </button>
    <div ng-repeat="city in cities">
     <select ng-model="cities_$index"
          ng-options="n.id as n.name for n in citiesList"
          class="form-control"
         ng-required="true">
    <option value="">-- Choose City --</option>
                                </select>
    </div>
```

Angular Controller :

```
$scope.addRow = function () {
 var newrow = [];
 if ($scope.cities.length === 0) {

                newrow.push({ 'cities': $scope.cities_0 });
            }
            else {
                $scope.cities.forEach(function (row, key) {

                    var city= '$scope.cities_'+key; // in php i can do this
//but i dont know how to do it with Js/Angular

                    console.log('row' + city);

                    newrow.push({ 'cities': city});

                    console.log(newrow);
                });
            }
 $scope.cities.push(newrow);
}
```

I tried this to retrieve the values from the cities selected but i have undefined values.

```
$scope.send = function () {

          angular.forEach($scope.cities, function (value, key) {

                console.log(value.id); // the id from the ng-options
        };
```

In a regular html code i just add `name="city"` and i retrieve all the cities added in my input box. But how i can retrieve thoses cities from the ng-model in my controller ?

I know i'm doing something wrong, but since i'm new with angular i'm trying !!

Thank you

Comment: wouldn't it just be 'datas' in your case that would hold the array?

Comment: Please include your controller code so that we don't have to assume anything.

Comment: I updated my first question and i added the controller code for a better comprehension of my need

Answer (score 0):

supposing that the key (city) is inside your datas array, you can do :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
 <input type="text">{{data.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my first question for a better comprehension of my need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` is still unique. What you are missing here is that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each item. Therefore, the value of `ng-model` is unique for EACH child scope. `ng-model` doesn't behave the same way as plain HTML input and having multiple inputs with the same `ng-model` will only point to the same object in memory. And not, "add up" values to the property city as you would expect in plain HTML inputs.

If you are using the object `datas` in your `ng-repeat`, it's kind of common practice that your `<input />` would bind to a item property of `datas`.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <input type="text">{{data.city}}
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my first question for a better comprehension of my need. Thanks

Comment: Keep your <select /> outside the ng-repeat. Reuse the same <select /> to add new cities. Use ng-repeat only to display the collection of chosen cities.